Xdebug hangs, and then crashes
I have this in php.ini:
extension=php_xdebug-3.4.0beta1-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
;xdebug.mode=coverage
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.trigger_value=PHPSTORM
xdebug.log_level=11
xdebug.log="c:\Dolgok\xampp\php\xdebug.log"
;xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms=2000

I also installed "Xdebug helper" extension into Firefox. I'm using PhpStorm, but this time its not started, just in case.
So I load the site which hangs, and then crashes. The log:
[28976] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:16.509405
[28976] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[28976] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[28976] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[19980] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:20.358385
[19980] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[19980] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[19980] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[30180] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:23.136012
[30180] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[30180] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[30180] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[34364] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:25.950401
[34364] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[34364] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[34364] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[17784] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:28.711704
[17784] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[17784] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[17784] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[26356] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:31.735895
[26356] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[26356] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[26356] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[36932] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:35.965129
[36932] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[36932] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[36932] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[36808] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:40.394103
[36808] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[36808] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[36808] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[16096] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:43.881391
[16096] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[16096] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[16096] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'
[38212] Log opened at 2024-11-26 22:48:47.094104
[38212] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[38212] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[38212] [Config] DEBUG: The trigger value 'PHPSTORM' matched the shared secret 'PHPSTORM' for mode 'debug'

Just what can it be?

ok, I succeed! By using this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html
I think the key was, instead of this:
extension=php_xdebug-3.4.0beta1-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll
I must use this:
zend_extension=php_xdebug-3.4.0beta1-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll
